# Meaning of "let bygones be bygones"

Tags: meaning, idioms

What is the exact meaning of the phrase *let bygones be bygones*?

If I had a fight with my best friend and then say it, which of the following does it mean?

1. I want to forget the past and reconcile and get back to friendship.
2. I want to forget the past but not reconcile and get back to friendship.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A ["bygone"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bygones) is a thing that happened in the past. A definition given of this [idiomatic expression](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/let_bygones_be_bygones) is:

> To ignore or disregard a past offense (when dealing with another individual

Thus, you've already forgiven that past offense which that person, and presumably you want to get back to being friends.

As far as I know, this phrase is always used in reconciliation. For example, when two friends fight(as in your case), and they come back together, their conversation might run something like this:

> A: I'm really sorry for what happened last week
>   B: Come, come, let bygones be bygones. What's done cannot be undone. Let's be friends again.
>   A: Sure mate!

In my personal experience, "let bygones be bygones" is used for reconciliation(your first interpretation)

Comment: To let a bygone be a bygone is to make that which is in past stay in the past and thus not affect the future.

Answer (score 9):

[Let bygones be bygones](http://www.goenglish.com/LetBygonesBeBygones.asp) is used in a conciliatory tone.So, yes, it means you're putting the disagreements behind you and getting back to being friends.

Answer (score 5):

from [The Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/let-bygones-be-bygones.html):

> So, there is a little more to the phrase 'let bygones be bygones' than
>   to the more literal 'let sleeping dogs lie' or the old proverb 'let
>   all things past, pass' that was recorded by John Heywood in his 1562
>   edition of Proverbs. 'Let bygones be bygones' uses both meanings of
>   the word 'bygones' and means, in extended form, 'let the
>   unpleasantness between us become a thing of the past'.

So I think, the meaning of the phrase is closer to your first meaning versus the second.

Answer (score 0):

Forget the past, turn over a new leaf. The past is history!